# How is the Unity tag suggested?

Tags: support, suggested-tags

It's just a general query, no big thing. I'm just curious.

I've noticed it a lot of times, but today when I was asking a question regarding adding transparency to windows and dialog boxes, mechanism suggested the Unity tag.

The suggested tags were LibreOffice, Firefox, and Unity. The former two were suggested because I made mention of them. But I never mentioned Unity. Of course the tag suggested was totally appropriate, as the question is related to Unity framework.

So I was just wondering how does the mechanism get it that I'm talking about Unity framework when I never make a mention of it?

Does it check for other words, like window or dialog, to suggest Unity?

Comment: Currently [the questions identified as being related](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8527335/) to [Can application windows/dialogs be given transparency?](http://askubuntu.com/q/533899/22949) (in the "Related" column on the right) are all tagged [tag:unity]. I'm not sure if they are listed because your question is tagged that way, or if they were already listed and the [tag:unity] tag was recommended based on their tagging. Do you know if the same questions came up as similar, while you were composing your post but before you added the [tag:unity] tag?

Comment: @EliahKagan it's supposed to look at [various things apart of tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20473/213575) but lately I've never seen it working that way.

Comment: I would say the question suggestions didn't change even after picking the unity tag. But I'm not fully sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magic!

... not really. The system uses a Bayesian-like method to check the content and title of your question, looks at previously asked questions with similar word choices, then suggest the tags that deems appropriated (or so it should be). [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212310/213575) you can see the original post describing how it works.

That's why retagging is important, because it teach the system which questions should use which tag.